# Splitting output into blocks of 4 chars and a bruteForce method

Tags: java, regex, split

So I have a "Caesar Cipher" written for a java assignment but I'm missing 2 required components that I can't figure out with the limited knowledge of Java I have thus far.

I need to further encrypt my output by splitting the the outputted string into chunks of 4 chars.
ie AFSD GRTH WRGD

I tried looking up java methods from the standard library but I haven't learned regex yet and I can't use guava since I'm submitting this via email. 
This hasn't been covered in class yet either.

I also need to include a bruteForce method that encrypts my plainText, but outputs cipherText for every possible key (0-25). 
I've tried using a while loop that sets the shiftKey at 0 and increments the key by 1 at the end of the loop but that outputted a crazy mess.

```
public String bruteForce(String plainText) {
    plainText = plainText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    String cipherText = "";
    int shiftKey = 0;
    while (shiftKey <= 26) {
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
            int charPosition = alphabet.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
            char replaceVal = this.alphabet.charAt(keyVal);
            cipherText += replaceVal;
            shiftKey++;
        }

    }
    return cipherText.toUpperCase();
}
```

this is my code so far

```
class CaesarCipher {
private final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public String bruteForce(String plainText, int shiftKey) {
    plainText = plainText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    String cipherText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = alphabet.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
        int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
        char replaceVal = this.alphabet.charAt(keyVal);
        cipherText += replaceVal;
    }
    return cipherText.toUpperCase();
}

public String encrypt(String plainText, int shiftKey) {
    plainText = plainText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    String cipherText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = alphabet.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
        int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
        char replaceVal = this.alphabet.charAt(keyVal);
        cipherText += replaceVal;
    }
    return cipherText.toUpperCase();

}

public String decrypt(String cipherText, int shiftKey) {
    String plainText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = this.ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(i));
        int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;
        if (keyVal < 0) {
            keyVal = this.ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
        }
        char replaceVal = this.ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
        plainText += replaceVal;
    }
    return plainText.toUpperCase();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String plainText = "this; is s'ome te.xt with punct";
    int shiftKey = 4;

    CaesarCipher cc = new CaesarCipher();

    String cipherText = cc.encrypt(plainText, shiftKey);
    System.out.println("Plain  Text :" + plainText);
    System.out.println("Cipher Text :" + cipherText);
    String PlainText = cc.decrypt(cipherText, shiftKey);
    System.out.println("Plain Text  :" + PlainText);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Four Chunks**

Here's what I've been able to come up with for splitting the string into chunks of four:

```
public  String[] splitIntoFour(String input){
    int chunkNum = 1+(input.length() / 4);
    String[] chunks = new String[chunkNum];
    for(int i = 0; i < chunkNum; i++){
        int startIndex = i*4;
        int endIndex = (i+1)*4;
        if(i == (chunkNum - 1))
            endIndex = input.length();
        chunks[i] = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

This method takes your string, divides it's length by four and adds one, in case it's not divisible by four. It creates an array of Strings, where each element is then going to be a chunk of four letters. Then, for each chunk, you take a substring of the input, the beginning index is calculated as a multiple of four and the end index as well. Except if the loop is on it's final iteration, in which case the end index is calculated as the length of the input. This is done to account for any input which is not divisible by four.

**Brute Force Method**

As for your brute force method, you probably want to give the output as an array as well, considering you output is 26 different strings, then it's just a matter of running a loop which encrypts the input with each key by using your other encryption method, considering you implemented that correctly.

```
public String[] bruteForce(String plainText) {
    String[] cipherText = new String[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < cipherText.length; i++)
        cipherText[i] = encrypt(plainText, i);
    return cipherText;
}
```

Just as a side note, brute force decryption is actually just as easy, just change the `encrypt(String)` method inside the loop into your `decrypt(String)` method:

```
public String[] bruteForceDecrypt(String cipherText) {
    String[] plainText = new String[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < plainText.length; i++)
       plainText[i] = decrypt(cipherText, i);
    return plainText;
}
```

**Printing Arrays**

Here's are two examples, using the brute force method, they will both print out twenty six different strings:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    CaesarCipher cipher = new CeasarCipher();
    //This variable contains 26 strings, returned from the bruteForce() method
    String[] cipherText = cc.BruteForce("This is an example text");
    //For each string in cipherText, print it out
    for(String string : cipherText)
        System.out.println(string);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    CaesarCipher cipher = new CeasarCipher();
    //This variable contains 26 strings, returned from the bruteForce() method
    String[] cipherText = cc.BruteForce("This is an example text");
    //Access each string in cipherText through it's index
    for(int i = 0; i < cipherText.length; i++)
        System.out.println(cipherText[i]);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: how would I call/implement these methods? I'm not too familiar with using methods with arrays. When I tried calling the brute force method with String[] bplainText = cc.bruteForce(plainText);it outputted "[Ljava.lang.String;@3b7a687b"

Comment: Here's a basic explanation on what arrays are:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html
I've also added some code to print out an array in my answer

Comment: By the way, the output you got was returned from a call to the object's `toString()` method, you will need to access each `String` object in the array to print it individually, this is what I added to my answer.